# How to connect existing flutter project with IOS emulator and xCode? Getting error Error running pod install

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

I am trying to run my flutter project on IOS emulatior, but getting these 2 errors

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.

This is the whole output
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like pod cache issue

```
flutter packages get
cd ios
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
pod deintegrate
rm Podfile.lock
pod install --repo-update
```

Try clearing your pod cache, removing your derived data, and run again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got the following response [!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).